# Find sum of all values in dict of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have dictionary like below,

```
 {
    'AAA': 
        {'NKA': 2, 'total': 4, 'Cleared': 2, 'NRM-TY': 3, 'KLAOO': 1, 'COREI': 1, 'MFTT': 2}, 
    'DDD': 
        {'Cleared': 2, 'total': 1, 'KLAOO': 1, 'COREI': 1, 'NRM-TY': 1}, 
    'NNN': 
        {'Cleared': 1, 'total': 1, 'KLAOO': 4,}, 
    'AANN': 
        {'Cleared': 1, 'total': 1, 'NRM-TY': 2}
}
```

I need to get sum of all the keys value like below,

```
{'NKA': 2, 'total': 7, 'Cleared': 6, 'NRM-TY': 6, 'KLAOO': 6, 'COREI': 2, 'MFTT': 2}
```

I can able to achieve this using below code,

```
result = {}
for k,v in a.items():
    for p,q in v.items():
        if p in result:
            result[p] += q
        else:
            result[p] = q
```

I just wanted to know is there any simple way to do the same...

Comment: `sum(sum(v.values()) for v in a.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also consider using the pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(your_dict).sum(axis=1)
```

You get:

```
COREI      2.0
Cleared    6.0
KLAOO      6.0
MFTT       2.0
NKA        2.0
NRM-TY     6.0
total      7.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `collections.Counter`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter
data = {
    'AAA': 
        {'NKA': 2, 'total': 4, 'Cleared': 2, 'NRM-TY': 3, 'KLAOO': 1, 'COREI': 1, 'MFTT': 2}, 
    'DDD': 
        {'Cleared': 2, 'total': 1, 'KLAOO': 1, 'COREI': 1, 'NRM-TY': 1}, 
    'NNN': 
        {'Cleared': 1, 'total': 1, 'KLAOO': 4,}, 
    'AANN': 
        {'Cleared': 1, 'total': 1, 'NRM-TY': 2}
}

result = Counter()    
for _, v in data.items():
    result += Counter(v)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'total': 7, 'NRM-TY': 6, 'Cleared': 6, 'KLAOO': 6, 'NKA': 2, 'COREI': 2, 'MFTT': 2})
```